# Read multiple XML files into a XML class structure

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I would like to Read and Deserialize more than one XML file into my XML class structure given a list of strings consisting of file names.
Obviously when reading ONE xml file, you can go like this:

```
XmlRoot file = null;
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlRoot));
using (XmlReader read = XmlReader.Create(FileName))
{
    file = (XmlRoot)ser.Deserialize(read);
{
```

Which will deserialize the XML file into the class structure?

It is not possible to have a list with file names and use a foreach loop to iterate over them, reading and deserializing one by one as it would theoretically result into multiple root elements being read, deserialized and replicated in the class structure.

So in general I would like to deserialize each file and append the required master elements to a root object.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? It would be of great help.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Excuse me for my English, as I am not a native speaker. If you need further information, just tell me!

Comment: You want to de-serialize multiple xml-files to a single object? Why do you need that? Usually *one single* xml matches exactly *one single* object of your xml-root-element. Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Because the xml files are containing our language information for the 
localization and they are split up into multiple smaller files. Thus we would still be able to export them as a single file all together.

Comment: I can't recall anything that does that. You'll have to merge somewhere.. Either create 1 single xml payload from all the files and then deserialize that or perferably deserialize each file and append the required elements to a master root object.

Comment: @Wheels73 That is excactly what i thought of, sorry if it wasn't clear by the text i provided.

Comment: @joshi422 - No problem. Try using Linq XML. I find it easier to navigate documents and extract and append nodes.

Comment: Make a List<XmlRoot> files = new List<XmlRoot>();  Then add each serialized file to list : files.Add(file);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem for myself.
First i created a XDocument for the first file i read, afterwards i iterate through the other documents creating a new XDocument for every xml file and try to get the elements after the root (Language in my case) and add it to the root of the XDocument created outside the loop.

```
        XDocument lDoc = new XDocument();
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var fileName in multipleFileNames)
        {
            try
            {
                counter++;
                if (lCounter <= 1)
                {
                    doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(fileName);
                    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = doc2.Element("Language")
                        .Elements();

                    doc.Root.Add(elements);
                }
            }
            return Deserialize(lDoc);
```

Afterwards i call the Deserialize method, deserializing my created XDocument like this:

```
    public static XmlLanguage Deserialize(XDocument doc)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlLanguage));
        return (XmlLanguage)ser.Deserialize(doc.CreateReader());
    }
```